# How can I name a file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Very basic problem:

I am customizing the invoice template for automatic new invoice number generation & auto-saved in excel.
My invoice number format is: ABC/0001/2021-2022 (Company name which is fixed + forward slash + Invoice number will keep auto-update with every invoice + forward slash + financial year)

I am autosaving the invoice in xlsx & pdf format and the file name will be saved as per the invoice number format("ABC/0001/2021-2022 or whatever format u put").

Now for me, it is not happening because my invoice number format has a forward slash which is an invalid character for the file name.

So I want to autosave my file as ABC-0001, ABC-0002, and so on.

Sharing the code:

```
Sub NextInvoice()
    LeftPart = Left(Range("D12").Value, 4)
    Midpart = Mid(Range("D12").Value, 5, 4) + 1
    Midpart = Format(Midpart, "0000")
    EndPart = Mid(Range("D12").Value, 9, 10)
    Range("D12").Value = LeftPart & Midpart & EndPart
End Sub

Sub SaveInvoiceBothWaysAndClear()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    ' Create the PDF First
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Arrow: Pentagon 6").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Arrow: Left-Right 7").Delete
    NewFN = "D:\My data\Invoice\PDF\ABC-" & Range("D12").Value & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFN, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    ' Next, Save the Excel File
    NewFN = "D:\My data\Invoice\Excel\ABC-" & Range("D12").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Range("A20:C29").ClearContents
    NextInvoice
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use Replace

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim NewFN  As String
    NewFN = "D:\My data\Invoice\PDF\" & Replace(Range("D12").Value, "/", "-") & ".pdf"
    MsgBox NewFN
End Sub

Sub NextInvoice()
    Dim ar
    ar = Split(Range("D12"), "/")
    ar(1) = Format(ar(1) + 1, "0000")
    Range("D12") = Join(ar, "/")
End Sub
```